# I am compiling a kernel that I built for a course and trying to build it gives an error

Tags: c, operating-system, kernel

I took a course about kernel development and when i try running the build.sh script it gives me an error

Error: ./src/kernel.c:125:14: error: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Werror=pointer-to-int-cast]

Screenshot:

[image: terminalerrorscreen]

Please note I had taken the source code link from the course after completing it and tried building it src link: https://github.com/nibblebits/PeachOS

Code:

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include "idt/idt.h"
#include "memory/heap/kheap.h"
#include "memory/paging/paging.h"
#include "memory/memory.h"
#include "keyboard/keyboard.h"
#include "string/string.h"
#include "isr80h/isr80h.h"
#include "task/task.h"
#include "task/process.h"
#include "fs/file.h"
#include "disk/disk.h"
#include "fs/pparser.h"
#include "disk/streamer.h"
#include "task/tss.h"
#include "gdt/gdt.h"
#include "config.h"
#include "status.h"

uint16_t* video_mem = 0;
uint16_t terminal_row = 0;
uint16_t terminal_col = 0;

uint16_t terminal_make_char(char c, char colour)
{
    return (colour << 8) | c;
}

void terminal_putchar(int x, int y, char c, char colour)
{
    video_mem[(y * VGA_WIDTH) + x] = terminal_make_char(c, colour);
}

void terminal_backspace()
{
    if (terminal_row == 0 && terminal_col == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (terminal_col == 0)
    {
        terminal_row -= 1;
        terminal_col = VGA_WIDTH;
    }

    terminal_col -=1;
    terminal_writechar(' ', 15);
    terminal_col -=1;
}

void terminal_writechar(char c, char colour)
{
    if (c == '\n')
    {
        terminal_row += 1;
        terminal_col = 0;
        return;
    }

    if (c == 0x08)
    {
        terminal_backspace();
        return;
    }

    terminal_putchar(terminal_col, terminal_row, c, colour);
    terminal_col += 1;
    if (terminal_col >= VGA_WIDTH)
    {
        terminal_col = 0;
        terminal_row += 1;
    }
}
void terminal_initialize()
{
    video_mem = (uint16_t*)(0xB8000);
    terminal_row = 0;
    terminal_col = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < VGA_HEIGHT; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < VGA_WIDTH; x++)
        {
            terminal_putchar(x, y, ' ', 0);
        }
    }   
}



void print(const char* str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        terminal_writechar(str[i], 15);
    }
}


static struct paging_4gb_chunk* kernel_chunk = 0;

void panic(const char* msg)
{
    print(msg);
    while(1) {}
}

void kernel_page()
{
    kernel_registers();
    paging_switch(kernel_chunk);
}

struct tss tss;
struct gdt gdt_real[PEACHOS_TOTAL_GDT_SEGMENTS];
struct gdt_structured gdt_structured[PEACHOS_TOTAL_GDT_SEGMENTS] = {
    {.base = 0x00, .limit = 0x00, .type = 0x00},                // NULL Segment
    {.base = 0x00, .limit = 0xffffffff, .type = 0x9a},           // Kernel code segment
    {.base = 0x00, .limit = 0xffffffff, .type = 0x92},            // Kernel data segment
    {.base = 0x00, .limit = 0xffffffff, .type = 0xf8},              // User code segment
    {.base = 0x00, .limit = 0xffffffff, .type = 0xf2},             // User data segment
    {.base = (uint32_t)&tss, .limit=sizeof(tss), .type = 0xE9}      // TSS Segment
};

void kernel_main()
{
    terminal_initialize();
    memset(gdt_real, 0x00, sizeof(gdt_real));
    gdt_structured_to_gdt(gdt_real, gdt_structured, PEACHOS_TOTAL_GDT_SEGMENTS);

    // Load the gdt
    gdt_load(gdt_real, sizeof(gdt_real));

    // Initialize the heap
    kheap_init();

    // Initialize filesystems
    fs_init();

    // Search and initialize the disks
    disk_search_and_init();

    // Initialize the interrupt descriptor table
    idt_init();

    // Setup the TSS
    memset(&tss, 0x00, sizeof(tss));
    tss.esp0 = 0x600000;
    tss.ss0 = KERNEL_DATA_SELECTOR;

    // Load the TSS
    tss_load(0x28);

    // Setup paging
    kernel_chunk = paging_new_4gb(PAGING_IS_WRITEABLE | PAGING_IS_PRESENT | PAGING_ACCESS_FROM_ALL);
    
    // Switch to kernel paging chunk
    paging_switch(kernel_chunk);

    // Enable paging
    enable_paging();

    // Register the kernel commands
    isr80h_register_commands();

    // Initialize all the system keyboards
    keyboard_init();
        
    struct process* process = 0;
    int res = process_load_switch("0:/blank.elf", &process);
    if (res != PEACHOS_ALL_OK)
    {
        panic("Failed to load blank.elf\n");
    }


    struct command_argument argument;
    strcpy(argument.argument, "Testing!");
    argument.next = 0x00; 

    process_inject_arguments(process, &argument);

    res = process_load_switch("0:/blank.elf", &process);
    if (res != PEACHOS_ALL_OK)
    {
        panic("Failed to load blank.elf\n");
    }

    strcpy(argument.argument, "Abc!");
    argument.next = 0x00; 
    process_inject_arguments(process, &argument);

    task_run_first_ever_task();

    while(1) {}
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and copy&paste the error message **as text** and [format it as code](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) instead of showing a screenshot. For what target are you trying to build? Maybe your target uses pointers of 64 bit size?

Comment: This looks like 32bit code compiled with compiler that targets a 64 bit system. `(uint32_t)&tss` only makes sense if the target system is 32 bit (where the size of a pointer is 32 bits)

Answer (score 1):

the data member `base` should be declared as uint32_t within `gdt_structured` struct